# How do I convert an iPhone 720p video into a similar quality Flash video using ffmpeg?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, video-conversion

What are the proper arguments to ffmpeg to covert an iPhone4 720p video into a similar quality Flash video?

I tried the following which resulted in a low quality Flash video:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov movie.flv
```

What are the right switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Use this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -q:v 4 movie.flv
```

Change the `q:v` parameter to higher values for lower quality and lower file size.

Comment: The `sameq` option [does *not*](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/) ensure the video quality will be the same.